How can I gray out scheduled todos in org-agenda?
I have this function, which skips todos in org-agenda
(defun my/org-skip-function (part)
  "Partitions things to decide if they should go into the agenda '(agenda future-scheduled done)"
  (let* ((skip (save-excursion (org-entry-end-position)))
         (dont-skip nil)
         (scheduled-time (org-get-scheduled-time (point)))
         (result
          (or (and scheduled-time
                   (time-less-p (current-time) scheduled-time)
                   'future-scheduled)  ; This is scheduled for a future date
              (and (org-entry-is-done-p) ; This entry is done and should probably be ignored
                   'done)
              'agenda)))                 ; Everything else should go in the agenda
    (if (eq result part) dont-skip skip)))

..and called like this
;;skip scheduled 
(org-agenda-skip-function '(my/org-skip-function 'agenda))


Can I modify this to "gray out" the todo, instead?
I think there is a built in "gray out" function?

C-h f org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks  and read its source code: that will give you a hint of how to go about it,
